# php form no file no upload

Tags: php, file, upload

I'm making a BETA "video uploading site" but people can just press upload without uploading anything, and spam my database AND the video site, how can i make it only upload if there are a file attched

my code is:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("ip","username","password");
mysql_select_db("database");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    move_uploaded_file($temp,"uploaded/".$name);
    $url = "http://www.mysite.dk/videoer/uploaded/$name";
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `videos` VALUE ('','$name','$url')");
}

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Upload din video | Se videoer</title>

</head>

<body>

<a href="videoes.php">Videoer</a>
<form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload!" />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo "<br />".$name." Er blevet uploadet";
}

?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's called validation. http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/07/web-form-validation-best-practices-and-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check PHP's `$_FILES` object to ensure the user submitted data, not just check if the `$_POST['submit']` variable is set.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php